CaptainCasa: How to optimize grid with complex cells?
In CaptainCasa I have a grid with complex header and complex cells. I have two "views" for the cell - one that is always visible and is read-only and another one which is only visible on mouse hover and allows to change the data in the cell:
enter image description here
It's possible that the grid would have thousands of rows and I'm worried that this will slow down the grid.
How can I optimize this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Each grid's cell content is "multiplied out" at client side. The number of cells is "number of columns" * "sbvisibleamount".
The "sbvisibleamount" is the max number of grids rows which is sent from the server to the client. You may set the value directly (attribute FIXGRID-SBVISIBLEAMOUNT) or it is set internally - with a value of around 40 (depends on screen size). - So the number of grid items may be "several thousands" but the grid only renders e.g. 40.
Nevertheless: what you add is quite some content per cell. Optimizations are:

instead of 2 COLDISTANCE components use PANE-PADDING, and ROW-COLDISTTANCE
instead of IMAGE - LABEL use possibilities to directly define LABEL-IMAGE
load the items of the BUTTONMENU on request if they are individual items per cell; if the items are the same for all cells refer to POPUPMENUID (so all refer to the same definition)

And finally: in case of big grids (mannny columns) and really each cell being constructed the way you desribe: think about writing some client side control that combines what you want to do (in your case it is an image and text, overlayed with some button when hovered...). This reduces the "component noise" drastically, of course.
